# append data to select box using jquery, the data comes from a webservice call

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I have the following code:

```
$(document)
    .ready(
        function() {
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/RememberMeServer/rest/LifeEventService/events",
                dataType : "xml",
                success : function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('Event').each(function() {
                        var name = $(this).find('Text').text();
                        $('#droplistevents').append($('<option/>', { 
                            value: name,
                            text : name 
                        }));
                    });
                },
                error : function(xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
        });
});
```

What it does is a get request to a webservice running on that address and gets the data inside the `<Event>  <Text> </Text> </Event>`

but unfortunately i am not being able to add that information to the select box i have in my html file with id = "droplistevents".
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This actually works. i was calling the wrong js inside the html page that calls this.

I dont delete because this might help someone